# Sync Mac AddressBook with android phone, /without/ using the cloud?

Tags: mac, sync, android

Is there free or commercial software which will sync the
Mac AddressBook with an android phone [via cable to USB
port]

*without* putting the data in cloud (not even temporarily), and
  syncing all the Addressbook data, including all the notes?

A websearch found a 2013 article

[How to sync an Android phone to your Mac](https://www.macworld.com/article/2039052/how-to-sync-an-android-phone-to-your-mac.html)

gave a method using the cloud.

Comment: Your phone manufacturer will likely have a utility that offers this function.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this solution](https://www.sync-mac.com/android-sync.html) - it syncs contacts between Mac and Android for free and does this directly between devices, no cloud services required.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?